# Dialogflow webhook (Actions on Google). Should I be using RichResponse or not?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

Reading through the documentation for Actions on Google, I've built a browse carousel by using a rich response class and supplying it with a simple response, the carousel and some suggestion chips.

```
const carouselItems = [];
items.forEach(item => {
    const carouselItem = new BrowseCarouselItem({
        description: item.description.text,
        image: new Image({
            alt: item.title,
            url: item.image,
        }),
        url: item.link,
        title: item.title,
    })
    carouselItems.push(carouselItem)
});


conv.ask(new RichResponse({
    items: [{
        simpleResponse: new SimpleResponse("the simple response message"),
        carouselBrowse: new BrowseCarousel({ 
            items: [ browseCarouselItem1, browseCarouselItem2 ],
        }),
    }],
    suggestions: ["suggestion1", "suggestion2"]
});
```

After spending time doing this, I discovered that the rich response class appears to be unnecessary. In fact, I can get the same result by using `conv.ask()` three times in a row instead.

```
conv.ask("the simple response message");
conv.ask(new BrowseCarousel({
    items: [ browseCarouselItem1, browseCarouselItem2 ]
}));
conv.ask(new Suggestions([ "suggestion1", "suggestion2" ]);
```

With this discovery, I find myself uncertain of the correct approach. Does one of these methods replace the other? What is the best practice? I've used `RichResponse` a few times throughout my webhook and I'm now unsure if I am working with an obsolete class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not "obsolete", but it is unnecessary. The standard practice is to call `ask()` multiple times and have the library build the `RichResponse` object for you. But the library does use it internally, so it isn't obsolete.

When I use the actions-on-google library, I prefer to use the multiple `ask()` since I don't have to use all of them. I can include some of them in different blocks depending on what features were available or what responses may be appropriate.

Use whatever works best for you.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it is not really intended to be imported into the webhook I gather. That makes perfect sense, thanks for the help. P.S. I tried to upvote your answer but apparently, my account is too new for it to take effect :(

Comment: Glad the answer helps. (Odd about accepting/upvoting.)